# 403 and 404 errors on site. All paths correct

Tags: css, image, http-status-code-404, vps

I'm having trouble figuring this out. We just switched to VPS hosting through host gator, uploaded a site. Nothing by 404 and 403 errors for the image and css files. All paths are correct and all the files are uploaded. Here is the dev url:
198.20.251.19/~lstorage/

Comment: Are you sure your css path is correct as http://198.20.251.19/~lstorage/style.css? or is it somewhere in some folder. Like css.

Answer (score 0):

Your page does not link correctly to your stylesheets or javascripts.
Paths do not seem correct.

```
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

reports:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /~lstorage/style.css was not found on this server.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>
```

I assumed the path to your stylesheet is not /~lstorage/style.css.
Simply change to correct file path.

---

Your images embedded on the page are not missing they are being blocked at server level.

```
<img src="images/slide/bigstorage.jpg" width="290" height="200" alt="Plenty of space to store everything">
```

reports:

```
<html><head>
<title>403 Forbidden</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Forbidden</h1>
<p>You don't have permission to access /~lstorage/images/slide/bigstorage.jpg
on this server.</p>
<p>Additionally, a 404 Not Found
error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.</p>
</body></html>
```

**SOLUTION**

Folder and file permissions are incorrect. If you are using php then chmod to change the permissions to have read access.

```
600 : Only owner can read/write
644 : Only owner can write, others can read
666 : All uses can read/write.
```

Comment: when talking about the site style, you are right. but missing images has nothing to do with css because they are directly embedded on the page using `img` tag. all these problems has a universal solution by changing the url somewhere.

Comment: @Zafar Did this help you at all?

Comment: Paths are correct, Permissions are correct as well. I think Zafar is on to something, I'll have to dig around in cPanel and see.